# Unable to Save or Save As Excel File due to "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

Unable to save or saveas the Excel file (.xls format) using save() or saveas() method using Microsoft.Office.Interop in vb.net - vs2010

```
excelWorkBook.SaveAs(ExcelExportPath, 
    Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, 
    System.Reflection.Missing.Value, 
    System.Reflection.Missing.Value, 
    False, 
    False,Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared, 
    False, 
    False, 
    System.Reflection.Missing.Value, 
    System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value)
```

or

```
excelWorkBook.Save()
```

Both are not working.. That raise the exception as "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"

But savecopyas() working.. Is there any permission oriented problem.. 
Please help me to solve this issue..

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you google "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC" you'll find solutions.

Comment: I searched a lot. But that are all not worked for me, Still problem exists

Comment: your SaveAs looks incorrect.. I have just created a simple excel using Interop and I am able to successfully save my workbook.. I can paste a snippet of the Save and Close workbook so you can see ..

Comment: Do you plan on running this system on a remote server? Why are you using MS interop library? I would recommend against it due to having to have a license for Office and in the case of having multiple users on your system at once, it will drain the resources at an accelerated rate. If you are simply creating basic xls files, maybe a library like ClosedXML or something like it would be more sufficient.

Comment: @KevinBBurns can i hide column and set read only for particular column is available in ClosedXML?

Comment: @MethodMan if there problem in saveas means, what about save(), that also raise exception

Comment: @GowthamSelvam, yes.

Comment: @GowthamSelvam, the only caveat I can think of in your case if a constraint has to be .xls, and in that case, I would just recommend reading the file with ExcelDataReader and manipulating then saving it with ClosedXML to a .xlsx file, which has better support across different Office applications. The majority of my job now has me reading tons of spreadsheets and dumping them into tabular data for SQL.

Comment: For `.xls` use `Excel.XlFileFormat.xlExcel8`.